# segfault in vfprintf with corrupted stack

Tags: c, gdb

My core looks like that:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fe7bd2e3735 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fe7bd2ee329 in vfwprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) i frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fe7b73e6e20:
 rip = 0x7fe7bd2e3735 in vfprintf; saved rip 0x7fe7bd2ee329
 called by frame at 0x1b
 Arglist at 0x7fe7b73e6e10, args:
 Locals at 0x7fe7b73e6e10, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fe7b73e6e20
 Saved registers:
  rbx at 0x7fe7b73e6de8, rbp at 0x7fe7b73e6e10, r12 at 0x7fe7b73e6df0, r13 at 0x7fe7b73e6df8, r14 at 0x7fe7b73e6e00, r15 at 0x7fe7b73e6e08, rip at 0x7fe7b73e6e18
(gdb)
```

Is there any chance to look up what was about to be printed, so I can find it in my code?

Comment: There must be a bug somewhere in the code you didn't show to us.

Comment: Yea, I figured. That's what I'm trying to find out. I have about milion calls for various print functions in my code. I wanted to narrow it down by printed string.

Comment: `valgrind` might help to narrow it down.  I think @Jabberwocky was asking you to post the code.

Comment: when compiling, and when linking, include the option: `-ggdb3`  Then, instead of addresses, you would see file name, , function name and , line numbers in the back trace.

Comment: Do you know about `C` [built in macros](https://www.lemoda.net/c/line-file-func/) that can be used to locate _where_ things occur?

Comment: unfortunatelly ```valgrind``` is out of the picture, because of application monitoring system and as I wrote I would have to post few GB of code (which is copyrighted btw). I am looking, if someone know where in memory can I look for buffer that vfprintf wants to print (how can I find this place).

Comment: I am aware of built in macros, as well as debugging symbols but: 1. this problem occurs only on production site. 2. this is standard library function

Comment: disassemble vfprintf and see what registers it uses? Or just write a toy program using vfprintf and disassemble the call site

Comment: What was about to be printed is most likely a null pointer which caused the segfault.  I think you need to run in a debugger and track down with breakpoints.

Comment: The code that calls this standard function is what is at fault.  You're going to have to spend time (probably a lot of time, I'm sorry to say), tracking down where the problem occurs in your code.  It might well be a major overwrite of the stack — there is code copying a lot of data into a stack-allocated buffer that is far too small and the trampling corrupts the stack back-trace data, but the function hasn't yet returned.  It's likely to be frustrating finding it, and quote probably simply resolved once found.

Comment: if the code is compiled and linked wth `-ggdb3` then, when using `gdb` you can reference all variables, buffers, etc etc by name

Comment: Use `x/s $rsi` or `x/ws $rsi` to see the 2nd arg, which for `*f*printf` should be the format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the stack seems to be corrupted, you cannot view from where in the code this call to vsprintf arrived from.

I suggest you compile your code with gcc flags of `'-Wformat' and '-Wformat-overflow'` which are aimed for this purpose.

from gcc documentation (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> **-Wformat** Check calls to printf and scanf, etc., to make sure that the arguments supplied have types appropriate to the format string
> specified, and that the conversions specified in the format string
> make sense. ...
>
> **-Wformat-overflow**  Warn about calls to formatted input/output functions such as sprintf and vsprintf that might overflow the
> destination buffer. ...

If your code contains a lot of compilation warnings (which is a bad practice to ignore), and you want only the format warnings, you can configure the build to treat these warnings as errors by adding the compilation flags `-Werror=format -Werror=format-overflow`